# Connection refused when connecting with sequelize to aws rds

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services, sequelize.js

I have tried to connect to aws rds in every way possible and I'm getting a connection refused error when using sequelize so I wonder if there's a setting I need to set or include when making the connection. The code works on my local machine and if I push to heroku, however I need to use the aws instance for this project.

I used the sequelize CLI to generate an index.js file and the code for that is:

```
var path      = require('path');
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var basename  = path.basename(__filename);
const config    = require(path.join(__dirname,'../config/config.js'));
const db        = {};

console.log('config: ',config);

if (config.env === 'production') {
    console.log('i ran');
  var sequelize = new Sequelize(config.use_env_variable);
} else {
    console.log('else ran');
      var sequelize = new Sequelize(config.db.database, config.db.username, config.db.password, {
      dialect:config.db.dialect});
}
```

the error that is being thrown is:
[image]

as you can see the config variable is doing it's thing and I've made sure the env variables are set. I've triple checked to make sure the username and password were correct. I also tried using the end point that aws provides instead of localhost but that failed too. I've made sure to change the security settings on aws to allow any IP address to access it and I've successfully used mysql workbench to connect so there must be something else specific to sequelize or the code I'm using correct ?

**UPDATE**
my config.js file is as such:
[image]

Comment: post your `config/config.json`. The error says `127.0.0.1` for connection refused. This does not look right

Comment: I still this your env variables are not set/ set incorrectly. print your `env` variables to see the output

Comment: I have to keep them blued out, but you can see that they're being output as 'config: ...' above. I've tried changing the host to the aws endpoint, I've messed around with the port too.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone comes across this with connection issues to amazon...

Your host is set to "localhost", but this must be set to the host that you're connecting to (not from). In aws rds case this will look something like this:

some-rds-name-inserted-here.74389nctj.eu-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com

Answer (score -1):

Check If your  RDS network could limited to different zone.